# Xcode 9 Beta 5 on High Sierra Beta 6

Tags: xcode9-beta, macos-high-sierra

I currently using Xcode 9 Beta 5 on High Sierra Beta 6 to updated my Apps for Swift 4 and iOS 11...
But after I launch an App on Simulator or Device launchd_sim eats up all CPU.
It only goes down when I quit Xcode and restart it...

Anyone solution for this?

Answer (score -1):

As Beta-Stadium on both (High Sierra and Xcode 9) is finished, I could be a good Idea to test on productivity Environment and close this ticket, if the problem is solved. Otherwise you could open a new ticket on stable Release of the Software.